# wpf dynamic image loading exception

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am trying to load an image from my hard drive (not a project folder) dynamically.   When I hard code the path, the image loads just fine:

```
<Border>
    <Border.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="C:\Program Files\my program\Working Assets\Logos\background.jpg" />
    </Border.Background>
```

However, when I try to load the image dynamically, the path cannot be found.

c# file:

```
public static string BACKGROUND_IMAGE_PATH = "C:\\Program Files\\my program\\Working Assets\\Logos\\background.jpg";
```

xaml:

xmlns:localVariables="clr-namespace:my_namespace.StaticResources">

```
     <Border BorderBrush="{Binding ColorsBo.BorderColor, FallbackValue='Black'}">
            <Border.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="{x:Static localVariables:VC.BACKGROUND_IMAGE_PATH}" />
            </Border.Background>
```

When I look at the logs and copy the path that the compiler says it cant find, it takes me directly to the resource. Does anyone know why can't the resource be found when I try to load it dynamically?

Comment: not sure maybe try replacing "\" with "\\" as it might be a character thing
also please show how you fill the variable in your dynamic example

Comment: The first xaml code snippit works as expected.  In the second one, I am using double slashes beause otherwise the c# file would not compile.  VC.BACKGROUND... has the path with double slashes.

Comment: please show us how you initialize this VC.BACKGROUND_IMAGE_PATH

Comment: @DenisSchaf - I edited the question.

Comment: even if you enter a string into the ImageSource in xaml (the path to your file) it is not actually a string
ItemsSource need to be an ImageSource Type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding Source={x:Static localVariables:VC.BACKGROUND_IMAGE_PATH}}" />
```

---

For an explanation, see the Remarks section in [x:Static Markup Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/xaml-services/x-static-markup-extension?view=netframework-4.7.2):

> Use caution when you make x:Static references that are not directly the type of a property's value. In the XAML processing sequence, provided values from a markup extension do not invoke additional value conversion. This is true even if your x:Static reference creates a text string, and a value conversion for attribute values based on text string typically occurs either for that specific member or for any member values of the return type.

In contrast to the above, built-in automatic type conversion (e.g. from string to ImageSource) is applied to the value produced by a Binding.

Comment: It works!!!!  Can you explain why the binding syntax works and the direct path does not?

Comment: when you binding it it will be interpreted as if you entered it directly into xaml and get a BitmapImage from the given Source. If you set the source to the static resource directly it will use it as is and try to interpret your string as a BitmapImage what will fail

Comment: @nikotromus you could as well have made your static ressource of type BitmapSource to achive this

Answer (score -1):

The ImageBrush.ImageSource does not require a string
to make this work you need to create a new ImageSource

```
public static ImageSource BACKGROUND_IMAGE_PATH = new BitmapImage(new Uri("C:\\Program Files\\my program\\Working Assets\\Logos\\background.jpg"));
```